# How to remove unwanted spaces from new file created from variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, wmic

This Works fine when run as Admin from anywhere except Root.
It works saved as ANSI from Notepad - Unicode produces no output at all.

This Batch functions to create a new text file containing a directory listing of the Root using the volumeID as a variable in the filename. Note that running from a subdir circumvents the protected root from writing when UAC is on

PROBLEM IS: The created filename is padded with 12 extra spaces before the ext.

Question is: How to truncate the spaces or prevent them from being appended?

```
Rem BATCH CODE:---------------------------

Rem -----------Fetch VolumeID as Variable to use in output filename:

@echo off
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get volumeserialnumber
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%j In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%~d0'" Get VolumeSerialNumber') do (
  set v_VolID=%%j
  goto :DONE
)
:DONE
echo  SERIAL=%v_VolID%
echo %v_VolID%
Pause

rem --------- WRITE VolID.txt with Directory Listing
c:
cd\
dir *.*>"_____TEST Volume ID-%v_VolID%.txt"
endlocal & set "%2=%label_%" & goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `For` loop with this:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    'WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%~d0'" Get VolumeSerialNumber'
) Do For /F %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "v_VolID=%%B"
```